# AppsScript Store unique value per users across executions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to store data generated by one function, and retrieve it in another function within apps script. This value is unique to each user. I've tried doing userProperties, but that does not seem to carry properly. Is this possible within AppsScripts?

I'm running this within a google sheet that is publicly editable.

For example: In an assigned script that runs when a user clicks on an image, lets call it "onButtonClick()", it collects some information from the user (such as "what is your favorite cookie).

Then, in a trigger for an on-change event (which checks which cell was changed), get that user's saved 'favorite cookie'.

userProperties saves data for the owner of the document which can be accessed, but there is no way to tell what the current user's "favorite cookie" is without an accessible unique identifier.

It seems google wont let the script access 'confidential info' in a trigger such as onChange/onEdit, even once the OAuth scope of the script is authorized by a user (via the initial button press gathering the favorite cookie info).

If I could get a unique value for the user from the onChange/onEdit trigger, I would use that...but triggers don't let that happen.

Edit::
It is requested to have a minimal reproducible example.
Have OAuth scope for "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"

In main body of apps script:

```
function doGetEmailPermissions(){
//button action to get user to trigger authorization from script.
var userInfo=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  if (userInfo!=null){
     setProp("userId",userInfo);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Thank you for verifying '+userInfo+"!");
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You must be logged in with a google account!");
  } 
}

function doOnEdit(e){
//use neither method returns the editor's information
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Cell changed by:"+Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Cell changed by:"+e.user);
}
```

Create an installable trigger for onEdit to call 'doOnEdit'. Create a button in the sheet and assign the script "doGetEmailPermissions".
Clicking the button will correctly request the user's authorization to run the script, and respond with the user's email.
Making a change by anyone other than the owner of the doc, returns empty strings for the email/user info.

Comment: What does carry properly mean?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: onEdit is a simple trigger so you cannot perform operations that require permission.  You must use installable onEdit

Comment: the on edit trigger is an installed trigger that runs a function that I have named "doOnEdit". It calls the function, but when i reference the e.user, it returns empty string for everyone except the owner of the document.

Comment: Yes there are times that it will not return a users information.  In the documentation it states something to the effect that it depends upon a complicated set of protocols.

Comment: that is my problem and the reason for this question. what 'protocols' are needed to be able to acquire any of said information within the onEdit installable trigger?

Comment: As was required previously, please add a [mcve].

Comment: apologies, added a very basic example to the end of the original post

Comment: Google is not going to discuss that because it involves account security.

Answer (score 0):

#### Get and Set User Properties

```
function setProp(key,value) {
  const ps = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  ps.setProperty(key,value);
}

function getProp(key) {
  const  ps = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  return ps.getProperty(key);
}
```

Comment: the user properties are only edited by the owner of the document, not unique to the editors.

Comment: Then they are not actually userProperties